# Risk of Using Google Places API Key inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-places-api

I am currently trying to use Google Places API to add Autocomplete functionality into a Form.

I could use a Ruby Wrapper like this one:

https://github.com/qpowell/google_places

But Autocomplete functionality seems more like a client side action closer to that one:

https://github.com/kristianmandrup/gmaps-autocomplete-rails

Problem with client side code is when trying to use a Google Places API KEY to increase the rate limit:

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXX&amp;v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

- Isn't that risky to embed an API key inside client side code, making it accessible to anybody?
- Is there a way to use that client side code while protecting the API key?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729976/does-google-maps-javascript-api-key-v3-need-to-be-kept-secret-in-html-checked

Comment: You can set which http referrers the API key accepts

Comment: @DuncanTidd meaning it is thus not a big deal if the key is public?

Comment: Basically yeah. Unless there's something that I'm not aware of :)

Comment: There is no (good) way around exposing your api key for javascript API's which is why in most cases you can set the allowed domains and have a separate secret which is used on server side requests.